# Question about ChessBase closed because flagged as "chessbase help center question"

Tags: discussion

I posted this question: [Strange behaviour of ctg books produced with ChessBase/Fritz and used in DroidFish](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/32432/strange-behaviour-of-ctg-books-produced-with-chessbase-fritz-and-used-in-droidfi)

It is not my first question of this kind. Indeed, I could ask it to the ChessBase help center, but as many people knows, this isn't the best way to get information about ChessBase. ChessBase is the most used software in the chess community and I don't think that Chess Stack Exchange should treat question regarding ChessBase like that. That's my opinion, but the [Help Center](https://chess.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) also clearly stipulates that

> *These gray-area questions include topics of etiquette, psychology, software, books/articles/media, as well as other subjects. Chess-specific questions about programming a chess engine or other chess software are welcome.

Clearly my question is on topic. It is also on par with

https://chess.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Why was the question closed?

(Plus : I (and others) made some comments about the questions that were moved to a chat by [Brian Towers](https://chess.stackexchange.com/users/4418/brian-towers) with a clear intent to hide the discussion when nothing against CSE rules was in it.)

I perfectly understand the moderation principle, but I am not sure, for highly technical subjects like mathematics, hard sciences, computing or chess, that the pertinence of moderation is *only* correlated to a high reputation.

Last : the OP is not my life. I like the SE principle as well as chess, hence CSE, and I don't think that a serious SE site about chess should avoid subjects like ChessBase, for obvious reasons. (Look a the [stockfish](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stockfish) questions. One could also say: stockfish has a GitHub, go ask your stockfish questions there.) If the problem is that ChessBase is a commercial software, then I have solid arguments as well, but I don't want to be tl;dr. If it is not and if the CSE community can provide help for people to use any chess software better, we should be proud of it.

Comment: I suppose I can say is that questions about a chess site itself are offtopic to a degree and that there is a fine line between general software questions that can be answered and ones that are so specific that they are impossible to answer and thus "off-topic" in the sense that they are useless questions for the site.

Comment: Actually the question led to the identification in a bug in DroidChess (android app that LOT of people in the chess community use also) and its resolution. "Seeming impossible" is always relative.

Comment: That's why I said "seemingly" to *show* that it's possibly relative.